# confused about awk scripting

Tags: awk, command-line

directions state your script file will be tested on our system with the following command:

```
awk -f ./awk4.awk input.csv
```

> Write an awk script that will accept the following file and output the name and grade fields

[image: task1]

apparently, I created a bash script and it needs to be an awk script that will run with awk -f from the command line.
below is my code. is there an easy way to convert my bash scripts into awk scripts without having to redo everything? really confused about the directions.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
##comment create an awk script that will accept the following file and output the name and grade fields
##comment specify the delimiter as ","
awk -F, '

/./ {
##comment print the name and grade, which is first two fields
print $1" "$2

}' $1
```

Comment: Note that what you have done is neither a bash script nor an awk script. That won't work unless you explicitly call it with a shell like `sh awk4.awk` or `bash awk4.awk`. You want _either_ an awk shebang (`#!/usr/bin/awk -f`), in which case you don't have the `awk -F ...`, _or_ you want a shell shebang (e.g. ` #!/usr/bin/sh`) and then have the script as you show (but that would be a shell script, not an awk script).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an awk script, the contents are what you would provide to `awk` as commands. So in this case, that's:

```
/./ {
##comment print the name and grade, which is first two fields
print $1" "$2

}
```

However, this will make it tricky to use `-F ,` so instead set `FS` in a `BEGIN` block.

So your script would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
##comment create an awk script that will accept the following file and output the name and grade fields
##comment specify the delimiter as ","
BEGIN { FS = "," }

/./ {
##comment print the name and grade, which is first two fields
print $1" "$2

}
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/awk -f
##comment create awk script that will output the given data in the format given in word document
##comment specify the delimiter as ","
BEGIN { FS = "," }

/./ {
##comment check if the third field is online, if print online
if ($3 == "online")
printf("%s is an online student\n", $1)

##commentcheck if the third field is onsite, if print onsite
if ($3 == "onsite")
printf("%s is an onsite student\n", $1)
} $1

Comment: #!/usr/bin/awk -f
##comment create an awk script that will output the names of the students with a score that is higher than 75.
##comment specify the delimiter as ","
BEGIN { FS = "," } NR > 1 {
    if ($2 >= 90 && $2 <= 100)
        grade = "A";
    else if ($2 >= 80 && $2 <= 89)
        grade = "B";
    else if ($2 >= 70 && $2 <= 79)
        grade = "C";
    else if ($2 >= 60 && $2 <= 69)
        grade = "D";
    else
        grade = "E";
    print $1, grade;
} $filename

Answer (score 1):

You have written an `awk` script, but placed it in a script. This is your `awk` script:

```
/./ {
##comment print the name and grade, which is first two fields
print $1" "$2
}
```

Save it into a file `script.awk` and run like

```
awk -F',' -f script.awk inputfile
```

Now a few hints on your script:

`awk` commands look like `CONDITION {COMMAND(S)}`. If `CONDITION` is fulfilled for a line (record), `{COMMAND(S)}` is/are executed. If there is no `CONDITION`, `{COMMAND(S)}` is/are executed for all records, if there is/are no `{COMMAND(S)}` then the record is just printed whenever  `CONDITION` is met.

In your case:

1. `/./` is a regex that matches lines with any character ... so all but empty lines - it is pretty much redundant, as a condition
2. You use `" "` as separator between the variables, use `,` to apply the default value
3. You will need to provide using `,` as separator in the script in an initial `BEGIN`-block.

---

```
BEGIN {FS=","}
{print $1,$2}
```

If you want to use comma as output separator, too, use:

```
BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
{print $1,$2}
```

Answer (score 0):

An awk script is just a collection of awk commands that can be run by `awk`. There are two ways of writing an awk script:

1. Just write the awk commands in a text file and call with `awk -f /path/to/file.awk`. In your case, that would be:

   ```
   /./ {
   ##comment print the name and grade, which is first two fields
   print $1" "$2

   }
   ```

   And you would run it as:

   ```
   awk -F, -f /path/to/file.awk inputFile
   ```

   Or, if you need it to be run with just `awk -f ./path/to/file.awk inputFile`, without the `-F,` then set the field separator in the script itself:

   ```
   BEGIN{ FS=","}
    /./ {
   ##comment print the name and grade, which is first two fields
   print $1" "$2

   }
   ```

   And then run with `awk -f /path/to/file.awk inputFile`.
2. Write the commands but use the shebang to specify what interpreter should read the script. In your case, that would look like this:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/awk -f

   ## With this approach, you can't use -F so you need to set
   ## the field separator in a BEGIN{} block.
   BEGIN{ FS=","}
   /./ {
   ##comment print the name and grade, which is first two fields
   print $1" "$2

   }
   ```

   And you would then make the script exwecutable (`chmod a+x /path/to/file.awk`) and run it like this:

   ```
   /path/to/file.awk inputFile
   ```

Those are both awk scripts. The third option is to write a *shell* script instead and have the shell script run the awk. That would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

awk -F, '

/./ {
##comment print the name and grade, which is first two fields
print $1" "$2

}' "$1"
```

What you had was neither one thing nor the other: you were using an awk shebang but had a shell script instead of an awk script.